# How to generate excel file even when there is no data. Python pandas ExcelWriter

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I need to deliver excel file to assigned folder on weekly basis, but sometimes there are no data to be delivered.

In this case I still need an empty file with header and everything, just with no data.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'PolicyNumber':['Pol1','Pol2','Pol3','Pol4','Pol5'],
    'OfficeLocation':['San Diego', 'San Diego','San Diego','Vista','Vista'],
    'Premium':[800,300,650,200,700]
})


folder_list = ['San Diego', 'Vista']

for location, d in df.groupby('OfficeLocation'):
    for folder in folder_list:
        if folder == location:            
            d.to_excel(f'\\\\server\user\name\{folder}\{location}.xlsx',sheet_name=location,
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should enumerate over the folder_list, since the OfficeLocation dataframe is already fixed.  I added Los Angeles as an example.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'PolicyNumber':['Pol1','Pol2','Pol3','Pol4','Pol5'],
    'OfficeLocation':['San Diego', 'San Diego','San Diego','Vista','Vista'],
    'Premium':[800,300,650,200,700]
})


folder_list = ['San Diego', 'Vista','Los Angeles']


desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ["USERPROFILE"]), 'Desktop')
excel_name = "\\df" + "." + "xlsx"
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(desktop + str(excel_name), engine = "xlsxwriter")

try:
    for idx,foldername in enumerate(folder_list):
        subset = df[df['OfficeLocation'] == foldername]
        subset.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = str(foldername), index = False)

finally:
    writer.save()
```